# Remove underscore & Text after keywords from SOLR query response

Tags: solr

Currently my response looks like this( using sitecore here)

```
 {
    "category_t": "Image"
 },
```

I cannot rename the field in Solr Schema, but I would like to strip the "_" & the text after it so basically my search response will become `category: "image"` from `category_t: "image"`. Is there any way to achieve this ? Using Analyzer or Tokenenizer  or may be response writer .

Comment: Aren't you using the Sitecore.ContentSearch API? Why are you directly dealing with the JSON? Sitecore.ContentSearch does a pretty good job of hiding the JSON and interaction with Solr. All you have to do is map your fields and run your query.

Comment: You can use copyField in solr in schema.xml

Comment: @oyeme I did use copyfield nd is working fine, but was looking for other alternative.

Comment: @gabbar nope my data are coming from sitecore but those data are accessed by external sources and Iam using own custom cores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Field Name Alias](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-FieldNameAliases) to change the name of the field when you return it form a search.

Basically:

```
 fl=field1,field2,category:category_t
```

If you need to to this often or cannot change the search request itself easily, you can add the parameter as a default in the request handler (in the solrconfig.xml).